# systemd --user for normal graphical applications

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm trying to set up systemd to start some programs when I log in. I'm doing this by putting files in e.g. `~/.config/systemd/user/some.service`. This has worked for my emacs server service, which looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Emacs: the extensible, self-documenting text editor

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --daemon
ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/keyring/ssh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

This starts a background process and allows me to connect to the emacs service with `emacsclient`

What's not working is my `terminator` service:

```
[Unit]
Description=The only terminal emulator that seems to be somewhat decent

After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/terminator
Restart=always
Environment=DISPLAY=:0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

With this code in `~/.config/systemd/user/terminator.service` I can start terminator on the command-line with `systemctl --user start terminator`, but I can't get terminator to start automatically on (graphical) login. I've tried messing around with the `WantedBy` and `After` lines, switching between to `graphical.target`, `default.target` and `multi-user.target`, but it's really just guess work and hasn't helped.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

your terminator service file looks okay to me.
check below things
1. just check "default.target" file, is this below line present in that file
After=multi-user.target
2. if you write "WantedBy=default.target" then you need to create a soft link of terminator.service file inside "default.target.wants/" directory.

if this above two are correct, it should get start.

If still doesn't work, please remove "After=multi-user.target" this line, and change Wantedby as "WantedBy=graphical.target".

let me know the status of service after login
systemctl status terminator.service

Answer (score 0):

Systemd is not the right tool for this task because it doesn't know when you have finished logging in in a desktop environment and it's possible to launch terminator.  Instead, you could put a symlink to terminator's desktop file in your `~/.config/autostart` :

```
ln -s /usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
```

Most desktop interfaces (Gnome, KDE, Unity) will launch it when they start.

Comment: but if you do it this way you lose the automatic restart functionality. also if this is the problem systemd is doing a terrible job of communicating it to the user...